# Select one row from every table in database

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with about 20 tables. Every table has 52 rows the rows are the weeks in a year.

I want to select from every table one row.

For example, how would I select the information from every table for week 22?

I'm trying to solve this problem using PHP.

Comment: A huge UNION ALL is the quick fix. But why do you have these 20 tables? Perhaps you need only one table.

Comment: every table is a school and they order by us food for the kids . every thing works but  i just want to see of a week what the schools has orderd by use that week

Comment: Seems like a bad design. Can't you put all schools in one table!

Comment: no thats not possilbe

Comment: everthing works fine but only the list i want to see do's not work i don't know the php for that it tryed $sql = "SELECT table_name FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name = 'kdv' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "{$row[0]}<br>"; }

Comment: THAT works i see all tables but i want als see the info of week 22 of all tables

Comment: @StefanBouman "_no thats not possilbe_" Of course it's possible! You might not know how - but it's still possible. You might have a different problem that you ***incorrectly*** "solved" by splitting the tables in the first place - but it's possible (if you implement a better solution to your previous problem). You might have existing systems that depend on the different tables - and it's ***still*** possible! Stubbornly denying what's possible leads to a hacky "solution" that will cause more difficulty in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't re-design your db to have one common table for all schools, you can at least have a view that returns data for all schools:

```
create view all_schools as
  select t.*, 'school 1' as school from table1 t
  UNION ALL
  select t.*, 'school 2' as school from table2 t
  UNION ALL
  ...
  UNION ALL
  select t.*, 'school 20' as school from table20 t
```

Then you can use that view to return data for all schools in one single query, like:

```
select *
from all_schools
where weekno = 22
```